# When is unit testing appropriate?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, assert

I'm following along with a program tutorial and in it, the teacher is having a bunch of functions return a boolean to indicate success. They are written like so:

```
bool SomeFunc()
{
   //code....
   return true;
}
```

This means that you can write unit test which expect true for these functions and are one way to show that the whole function ran properly. To me, the way this would work is if, at a bunch of different points within that function, you had a bunch of different checks for things that returned false if an error occurs:

```
bool SomeFunc()
{
   if(!someThing)
      return false;

   return true;
}
```

But what if instead you just had a bunch of asserts within the function doing your checks:

```
bool SomeFunc()
{
   assert(someThing, "Error: thing not working");

   return true;
}
```

Then would there be a reason to still unit test this function if the asserts will just catch any bugs? The only thing reason I could think of is if you want your unit tests to work in release mode for these functions and then you would add both asserts and the if statements (since asserts are usually turned off in release mode).

Comment: Don't just test that the true cases return true. Also make sure the false cases return false. Failing well is just as important as succeeding.

Comment: Also one important thing. Besides testing that your function returns `true` at your first example above, the unit test may test whether the function is executed at all or not. A typical example of this is a function which returns void, but consequently executes some other functions in a row.

Comment: Given that `assert` is usually a no-op in production builds, maybe you want to raise an exception instead.

Comment: A boolean return type or return code is not really used for unit testing, but to communicate whether the function accomplished its task. For example if opening a file was successful. Return codes are more common in C than C++. In C++ it is preferable to use exception handling rather than return codes.

Answer (score 0):

Some times, we want to perform an action which may fail or not, in this cases yout will do something like:

```
if( function() )
{
    //doSomething
}
else
{
   //Handle error
}
```

If your function() fails and you call assert() from inside the execution of a program is stopped so you can manage nothing.

Imagene if you build a user program that read from console an int buy you type a char so the cast from char to int fails, would you like the program to crash or continue waiting until you type correctly?

Another option is raising an exception which you can catch from other block of code and handle it.